# Connect esp32 cam to pc

Tags: esp32, ftdi

I would like to know if there is a way to connect an esp32 cam via an esp32 to the pc to program it.

I have only found tutorials to connect it via an arduino or FTDI...

Answer (score 2):

ESP32-CAM doesn't have USB->serial converter so the only way to program ESP32 for the first time is via serial. After uploading sketch via USB-TTL converter you can use OTA to update ESP32 via Wi-Fi but if you don't have FTDI converter it's useless.

Another solution is to use arduino board as USB-TTL converter because converter is already included on most of the arduino boards (nano, UNO..).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a normal esp32 with a usb port that I can connect to the PC and a esp32 cam. So there isn't a way to connect them both in order to program the latter?

Comment: @DaniElHahn I think that ESP32 can be used as FTDI converter but if you have time it's better to buy normal converter because it will be always useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect it to a PC - but, as you said, only using an Arduino or FTDI.

You can't connect it directly.

The ESP32-CAM doesn't support USB for communications. FTDI allows the PC's USB connection to communicate with the ESP32-CAM's serial port. They can't communicate without some kind of adapter - that's what FTDI or an Arduino are for.